# Killing inconsistencies: the path to understanding

Tags: soft-question

This is a *very* soft question, and I ask it with some trepidation.

When I begin studying a new topic, I don’t feel I really understand it until I go to bed Friday thinking I’ve found an inconsistency in mathematics, spend Saturday mulling over the problem, and awaken Sunday seeing my mistake.

Do others have the same experience, or is it just me?

---

I don't mean I literally think there's an inconsistency. But the issue gnaws at me, making it impossible to think about anything else. Whereas if I'm stuck  solving a problem or completing a proof, I can let it go.

This experience always occurs in the context of a concrete example. Here's an instance, as best I can recall.

When I first started learning complex analysis, I computed a residue two different ways, getting different answers. Eventually I realized I was *unconsciously* assuming this "fact": if $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}f(z)=c\neq\infty$, and the residue of $g(z)$ at $a$ is 0, then the residue of $f(z)g(z)$ at $a$ will also be 0. (Hey, it's true if $c\neq0$! And if $c=0$, doesn't that create even more "pressure" on the residue to be 0?) As I said, I didn't realize I was assuming this ($f(x)$ and $g(x)$ were pretty complicated, and just a piece of the whole computation), and once I stated it explicitly I saw my error.

Comment: @JeanMarie I spend Saturday mulling over the issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie I was a little too cryptic in my original post. I’ve expanded it.

Comment: The best advice I can give is : don't stay alone with your problem, speak to (many) others or ask in forums like this one. This is also valid for our own own psychological balance : share with others, don't keep the burden for you. Reciprocally, share the burden of others, This is what makes life enjoyable...